# How to enable on-demand resources in MacOS Catalyst app

Tags: macos, on-demand-resources, mac-catalyst

The documentation for NSBundleResourceRequest says that it's supported in MacOS Catalyst but when I upload our app containing on-demand resources to the Mac App Store, App Store Connect shows "On Demand Resources No" on the MacOS build page.

The iOS build of the app works fine and App Store Connect shows "On Demand Resources Yes (156 Asset Packs)."

Is there a special setting somewhere to get them to work for a MacOS Catalyst app?

Comment: Documentation says the call are ignored. It seams on demand resources are not available with catalyst:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundleresourcerequest

Answer (score 0):

A side note: It is unclear why the class has an `Mac Catalyst 13.1+` tag under it. I interpret it as "`NSBundleResourceRequest` is available starting from iOS 13.1 on Mac Catalyst", but apparently it is not the case.